# c++ portable address encoding

Tags: c++, portability

I'm writing a software that, at some point must write internal addresses into a buffer. I wrote the following code which works. But produce warnings when cross-compiling to a target device with an address size smaller than 64 bits.

How can I make this portable without generating errors?
I would have expected gcc to ignore the warning due to the condition-always-false around the problematic statement. I get the same behaviour when doing this with a template (where i feed sizeof(void*()) as address_size).

```
uint8_t decode_address_big_endian(uint8_t* buf, uintptr_t* addr)
    {
        constexpr unsigned int addr_size = sizeof(void*);
        static_assert(addr_size == 1 || addr_size == 2 || addr_size == 4 || addr_size == 8, "Unsupported address size");

        uintptr_t computed_addr = 0;
        unsigned int i = 0;

        if (addr_size >= 8)
        {
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 56));
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 48));
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 40));
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 32));
        }

        if (addr_size >= 4)
        {
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 24));
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 16));
        }

        if (addr_size >= 2)
        {
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 8));
        }

        if (addr_size >= 1)
        {
            computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 0));
        }
        
        *addr = computed_addr;

        return static_cast<uint8_t>(addr_size);
    }
```

The code works. MSVC is able to optimize that to a single x86_64 instruction. It also works on a AtMega328p, but avr-gcc do throw these warnings.

```
/home/py/scrutiny-embedded/lib/src/protocol/scrutiny_protocol_tools.cpp:32:72: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
                 computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 56));
                                                                        ^
/home/py/scrutiny-embedded/lib/src/protocol/scrutiny_protocol_tools.cpp:33:72: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
                 computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 48));
                                                                        ^
/home/py/scrutiny-embedded/lib/src/protocol/scrutiny_protocol_tools.cpp:34:72: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
                 computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 40));
                                                                        ^
/home/py/scrutiny-embedded/lib/src/protocol/scrutiny_protocol_tools.cpp:35:72: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
                 computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 32));
                                                                        ^
/home/py/scrutiny-embedded/lib/src/protocol/scrutiny_protocol_tools.cpp:40:72: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
                 computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 24));
                                                                        ^
/home/py/scrutiny-embedded/lib/src/protocol/scrutiny_protocol_tools.cpp:41:72: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
                 computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 16));
                                                                        ^
```

In this case, I can make a static_assert on address_size to prove that it is indeed equal to 2. But still get the warnings.

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? If you're using C++17 or above, you can use `if constexpr` to make those branches compile-time. The problem is that even though the branch can never occur in practice, normal `if` statements aren't conditional at compile-time, so it's still able to statically see this

Comment: Ah darn. I am using c++11.  It's rejected by GCC. Would have been a nice solution though.

Comment: Your entire function could be simplified to `memcpy(addr, buf, sizeof(void*))`.  Change my mind.

Comment: endianess independence?

Comment: @Pier-YvesLessard - given that these address have little meaning anywhere but the current process, I don't see any value in trying to be endian correct when serializing to a buffer and back.

Comment: @selbie. Exactly, they're used outside this process. It's a debugging tool and the address is to be interpreted by a python process that communicate over some media. The message must always be encoded the same way, target being little or big endian.

Comment: Ok, after do your memcpy, use htonll or ntohll to convert.  I'll convert my comments to an answer.

Comment: I never said that the communication is through a socket. hton is not an option

Comment: `htonl` and similar are not limited to just sockets.  They are general endian conversion functions.  Also, there's another issue with your technique. What happens if the address size is different between local and remote.  That is, what happens if the encoder is on a 32-bit machine, but the decoder is on a 64-bit machine or vice-versa.

Comment: @selbie. This is not an issue. The remote machine handle this very well. it's by design.

Comment: Excellent. Then I stand by answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if constexpr (addr_size >= 8)
```

If C++17 is not available to you, you can suppress the warning

```
if (addr_size >= 8) {
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << ((addr_size >= 8) * 56)));
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << ((addr_size >= 8) * 48)));
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << ((addr_size >= 8) * 40)));
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << ((addr_size >= 8) * 32)));
}
```

If `addr_size >= 8` is true, it evaluates to 1 in the multiplication arguments. Otherwise, it would evaluate to 0, but the branch is not executed.

Shorter with  @RaymondChen's hint.

```
if (addr_size >= 8) {
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << (56 % (addr_size * 8));
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << (48 % (addr_size * 8));
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << (40 % (addr_size * 8));
   computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << (32 % (addr_size * 8));
}
// Will be shorter with constexpr unsigned int addr_size = sizeof(void*) * 8;
```

Alternative code

```
if (addr_size >= 8) {
   uint64_t tmp;
   tmp = static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 28;
   computed_addr |= tmp << 28;
   tmp = static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 24;
   computed_addr |= tmp << 24;
   tmp = static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 20;
   computed_addr |= tmp << 20;
   tmp = static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << 16;
   computed_addr |= tmp << 16;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying your 2nd solution. Seems nice for now. Will give you result soon.
3rd solution is a bit greedy on memory, It forces the device to allocate 64bits for a 16bits address.

Comment: May be a bit less wordy: `constexpr bits = 8 * sizeof(void*);` and then `computed_addr |= ((static_cast<uintptr_t>(buf[i++]) << (n % bits));`

Comment: Sorry for being picky. For your edit. putting the variable inside the scope might even be worse. Compilers don't always optimize the stack memory, so you might endup with a uint64_t + uint32_t + uint16_t on the stack.

Comment: All modern compilers recognize always false conditions and remove whole if-true-branches. In any case we here to find a solution for you. What is better and applying it with modifications to your code is up to you.

Comment: Ansolutely. Thank you. I will mark this as the answer as soon as I can confirm that GCC and MSVC don't generates crappy assembly.

Comment: Assembly identical with and without your c++11 trick! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would forgo bitpacking and just do an in-place conversion of bytes on little-endian devices.

To deserialize an address from big-endian, you only have to do this:

```
size_t decode_address_big_endian(uint8_t* buf, uintptr_t* addr)
{
    const size_t address_size = sizeof(uintptr_t);
    uint32_t test = 0x01020304;
    bool isLittleEndian = (htonl(test) != test); // isLittleEndian = (1 != *(uint8_t*)&test));


    if (isLittleEndian)
    {
        uint8_t tmp[sizeof(uintptr_t)];
        memcpy(tmp, buf, address_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < address_size/2; i++)
        {
            std::swap(tmp[i], tmp[address_size-1-i]);
        }
        memcpy(addr, tmp, address_size);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(addr, buf, address_size);
    }
    return address_size;
}
```

Comment: I really am not conviced by this solution. Altough it works, it adds a dependence on network library. They're not available out of the box on avr-gcc (loses portability points).  Also, it worsen the cyclomatic complexity with regards to the bitpacking approach, which make it harder for the compiler to optimize.  Actually, gcc, with -Os flag, can replace the whole bitpacking function by a single "bswap" instruction. While this approach requires 25 instruction + indirect addressing + branching.  It's a lot of hassle just to avoid bitpacking. What's the rationale to avoid it?

Comment: You can replace the `htonl` test with `isLittleEndian = (1 != *(uint8_t*)&test));`

Comment: Which do you need more of: portable code that is readable, smaller, and maintainable? Or speed?

Comment: I'd say: size first, speed second.  From my point of view, bitpacking is more readable, smaller, maintainable and even faster.  What is the rationale for not using bitpacking?

Comment: I'd say this is pretty tight: https://godbolt.org/z/rxz9erxYh

Comment: without the hton call it ideed get optimized properly. much better